# Cache GeoServer is not working. How to solve?

Tags: geoserver

I'm not able to work satisfactorily with the cache for GeoServer WMS. The WMS we are curling refers to the state of Goiás and often to present this layer takes few seconds. We also created a SLD to hover in a given municipality and sometimes gets to take 20 seconds to change the SLD.

I opted for better detail the problem including prints of the images in the document link:
https://docs.google.com/a/geoinova.com.br/document/d/1YSUPg21P0EZb78G0ojX77mUSpPiJld7Fg7za9CVsB28/edit

Could anyone guide me in this regard how to proceed?

I thank the attention.
Diego.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check the cach settings in geoserver and make sure the inline caching is enabled. Or you can use a different url to get to the layer.

If you normally access layers like this

http://example.com/geoserver/wms

Then try this instead

http://example.com/geoserver/gwc/service/wms

The gwc stands for GeoWebCache.

For more information on turning on direct caching or using the url see [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html).